# Windows Store App Search Contract Blank Screen

Tags: vb.net, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I recently added the search contract to my app. It is working great! But, whenever I search in the app when it is not running, it only starts with a blank screen. I did the part to add search results even in OnSearchActivated method. But even if I remove the code that I added, the blank screen persists. I created a blank project and added the search contract to it. And it is working in it even when the app is not running. The issue seems to be with my app only. I cannot debug it because it is something that runs when the app is not even running. Tell me a solution.

Code in OnSearchActivated and OnLaunched

```
Protected Overrides Async Sub OnSearchActivated(args As Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.SearchActivatedEventArgs)
    Dim previousContent As UIElement = Window.Current.Content
    Dim frame As Frame = TryCast(previousContent, Frame)
    If frame Is Nothing Then
        frame = New Frame
        Common.SuspensionManager.RegisterFrame(frame, "AppFrame")
        If args.PreviousExecutionState = ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated Then
            Try
                Await Common.SuspensionManager.RestoreAsync()
            Catch ex As Common.SuspensionManagerException
            End Try
        End If
    End If
    frame.Navigate(GetType(SearchResultsPage1), args.QueryText)
    Window.Current.Content = frame
    Window.Current.Activate()
End Sub


Protected Overrides Async Sub OnLaunched(args As Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.LaunchActivatedEventArgs)
    AddHandler SearchPane.GetForCurrentView.SuggestionsRequested, AddressOf OnSearchPaneSuggestionsRequested
'Contains definition of arrays ExNam, ExAbbr, ExInst, etc. removed from here to shorten the code and focus on its logic
    If rootFrame Is Nothing Then
        rootFrame = New Frame()
        Train_Thy_Brain.Common.SuspensionManager.RegisterFrame(rootFrame, "appFrame")
        If args.PreviousExecutionState = ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated Then
            Await Train_Thy_Brain.Common.SuspensionManager.RestoreAsync()
        End If
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame
    End If
    If rootFrame.Content Is Nothing Then
        If Not rootFrame.Navigate(GetType(Instructions), args.Arguments) Then
            Throw New Exception("Failed to create initial page")
        End If
    End If
    Window.Current.Activate()
End Sub
```

'Also the namespace definitions are done at the top so they are not the issues neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a solution to debug your app : in VS2012, Right-click on your project in the **Solution Explorer**, then go to the **Debug** tab and in the **Start Action** section, check "***Do not launch, but debug my code when it starts***".

Now you can start your app from the Search Contract even if it is not running yet and debug it!

Now for your problem, I would suggest you to check whether the data is loaded before you actually search for something.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. The problem I guess is not about the data being loaded or not. It is more of the Search UI not even displaying. It shows a pure black screen. I think the problem is with the frame or page not loading. I did not touch the code of OnSearchNavigated. So, it should at least display the Search Page UI.

Answer (score 0):

You might be hitting the search activation with empty query string. Check your search activation handler, whether you are handling the blank query text case or not?

```
protected override void OnSearchActivated(SearchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    // your app initialization code here.

    Frame frame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.QueryText))
    {
        frame.Navigate(typeof(SearchResultsPage), args.QueryText);
    }
    else
    {
        // navigate to your app home page if the query text is empty. 
        frame.Navigate(typeof(Home), null);
    }

    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

Comment: It don't seem to be the issue. Thanks anyways. Because even if a blank query is passed, it could display Search results for "". The problem is that nothing is being displayed on the screen. It is a pure black screen.

Comment: good to share code for activated and onsearchactivated handlers, in that case.

Comment: sure, putting in the question itself.

Comment: its likely typo that rootFrame is not defined in the onlaunched method. Try to replace the search activated method contents with the contents from your other project where it is working. sometimes it is hard to get to the silly mistake by review. typically blank screen means that Window.Current.Content is not set properly and hence, the app is showing blank screen. but here it does not seem to be the case.

Comment: rootFrame is declared and defined immediately after the class definition of app.xaml.vb

NotInheritable Class App
    Inherits Application
    Dim rootFrame As Frame = Window.Current.Content

Comment: I solved the problem. It was because of the LoadState method had a variable I was using that was not yet initialized. I fixed it by the steps that Renaud Dumont told above.